# How cast collation when inserting data with different collation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I want to copy data from a table to another which has a different collation.

But when I execute my query, it returns an error.

```
INSERT INTO [des].[dbo].TableDes
    SELECT *
    FROM [src].[dbo].TableSrc
```

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Arabic_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: select column-name collate collation-name...

Comment: But why do you have identical tables, just with different collations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have to define `COLLATION` when we move data one `COLLATION` to another

```
INSERT  INTO [des].[dbo].TableDes 
SELECT  col1,col2,... COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
FROM    [src].[dbo].TableSrc
```

[COLLATION](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: tinka I did it but accur same error...
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Arabic_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: @MahdiH it is working on my machine and this is also `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`